# How do you use the power function in c++ with 3 parts?

Tags: c++

I need help with this a growth/decay equation.

```
answer = principle * pow(2.7,rate,number));
```

That is the code I have for that line and I want to calculate this equation as...

```
answer = principle * 2.7^(rate*number)
```

I am getting an error that pow function won't work for this scenario. Please note that I am using...

```
 #include <cmath>
```

Error:

```
.\Lab2.cpp(27): error C2661: 'pow': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments
```

Thanks

Comment: In your equation, you are multiplying the `rate` by `number` in order to get the exponent. Multiplication is also possible in C++.  I'll leave the rest as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Hint: You only have to change one character.

Comment: And it's not the Fighter-Magic User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto answer = principle * pow(2.7, rate * number);
```